# SSH Tunneling in Layman's term

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

What exactly is SSH tunneling? What is the difference between the terms: SSH Tunneling and Port forwarding? What is the exact difference between different types of SSH tunneling methods?

> Local port forwarding vs Reverse port forwarding vs Dynamic tunneling

What are the ideal scenarios where each type can be used?

Comment: A canonical answer and a layman's answer are very different things...

Comment: Sorry! All I wanted is a detailed explanation. Can I change it somehow?

Comment: Are you also interested in other common methods of securely connecting to remote LANs, such as VPNs or RDS?

Comment: Not actually. I've trying to understand these methods and having a hard time understanding the differences in these methods.

Comment: @Jason nah you can have a canonical layman's answer. SSH is a complex thing.. so where he asks for a layman's answer, he (and in this case it's clear), he's not asking for an explanation to the neighbour or his grandpa, he's somewhat technical and is asking for an explanation, that covers the ground of local,reverse,dynamic).

Comment: @barlop Exactly. I'm just having a hard time in visualizing the difference.

Comment: @RahilArora took me a long time to get my ahead around it and many times I thought i'd got my head around it but then had the insight that let me get my head around it more.. i'm still not sure how far my head has got round it. As a start, try contemplating the 4 aspects.. Who runs the SSH.EXE who runs SSHD.EXE who runs the regular client and who runs the regular server e.g. the VNC client and VNC server. So 4 elements there. And write them on paper 'cos it's a lot for the mind.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In layman terms, Secure Shell or SSH is established between two computer programs :

1. On the server side : A daemon (system service) that listens on a TCP/IP port and
   accepts connections. It receives encrypted packages of several types, which it executes.
2. On the client side : A client which connects to the server and transfers commands.

The connection between client and server uses encryption, so establishing in effect
a secure channel over an insecure network.
The term "Secure Shell" comes from the ability of the server to run a local shell
on the server computer, allowing the client to execute commands and see their result.
But SSH can also be used for many other purposes.

Both server and client use a known protocol to communicate, which means a known
format for their messages.
However, SSH can also do tunneling, which means the transfer of messages-within-messages
or protocol-within-protocol.
The server in this case acts as a switch or agent, transferring messages back and forth
between the client and its target, for example evading the local firewall :

[image]

The messages from the inner protocol are in this way encrypted and encapsulated
inside the SSH protocol.

Below are detailed some, but by no means all, of the uses of SSH.

## Executing remote commands

To run a command on a remote system without logging in, specify the command after the login information:

```
$ ssh host command
```

For example, to check remote disk space:

```
$ ssh host df
```

Another example for Linux is piping the microphone from one machine to the speakers of another:

```
$ dd if=/dev/dsp | ssh -C user@host dd of=/dev/dsp
```

## Copying files with ssh

For copying data and files over SSH, there are a few options.

It's possible to copy with the command cat. If you're trying to copy the output of a process instead of a file, this is certainly a reasonable route :

```
$ cat file | ssh -e none remote-host 'cat > file'
```

If these are going to be large files, you may want to use the -C flag to enable compression.

For copying files, the program scp works like cp, except it also accepts remote destinations :

```
$ scp .bash_profile matt@example.com:~/.bash_profile
```

For an FTP-like interface for copying files, use the program sftp.

## Local port forwarding

SSH allows secure port forwarding.

For example, suppose you want to connect from client A to server B but route traffic securely through server C. This is useful for evading firewalls.

From A, run:

```
A$ ssh C -L localport:B:remoteport
```

Then, to connect to B:remoteport, connect to localhost:localport.

If you use add -g, then anyone that can reach A may connect to B:remoteport through A:localport.

For example, suppose your work banned reddit.com.
Run this:

```
# ssh yourserver -L 80:reddit.com:80
```

And, set the address of reddit.com and www.reddit.com to 127.0.0.1 in /etc/hosts
(you will also need to disable any local web server).
Now, it will surreptitiously traffic to reddit.com through your yourserver.

If you do this frequently, you might want to add a special host:

```
Host redditfw
HostName yourserver
LocalForward 80 reddit.com:80
```

## Remote port forwarding

Alternatively, suppose you wanted to give remote machine B access to another machine, A, by passing securely through your local machine C.

Then, on C, you can run:

```
C$ ssh B -R remoteport:A:targetport
```

At this point, local users on B can connect to A:targetport through localhost:remoteport.

If you want to to allow nonlocal users to be able to connect A:targetport through localhost:remoteport, then set in the sshd_config file:

```
GatewayPorts yes
```

If you do this frequently, set up a special host in ~/.ssh/config:

```
Host exportme
HostName B
RemoteForward remoteport A:targetport
```

## SSH as a filesystem: sshfs

Using the FUSE project with sshfs, it's possible to mount a remote filesystem over SSH.
On the Mac, use Fuse4x.

Once it's installed, run:

```
$ sshfs remote-host: local-mount-directory
```

[source](http://matt.might.net/articles/ssh-hacks/)

Answer (score 4):

SSH tunneling is the same as port forwarding in this context, though SSH documentation and configuration parameters usually refers as the later one.

Tunneling or forwarding a port allows you to encapsulate TCP traffic inside a SSH connection. This could be used to

- encrypt traffic using the SSH connection.
- connect to any machine on the other side of the SSH connection as if they were local ports.

Local port forwarding is when the LISTEN port is established on the client side. I.e. you open a local port 80 on your machine, connected to someotherplace:80 on your server side.

Reverse port forwarding is when the LISTEN port is established on the server side. I.e. you open a remote port 8080 on the server, conected to your_proxy:8080

Dynamic acts as a SOCKS proxy.

Sample scenarios:

- you need to operate a GUI on the remote server. X are not encrypted and requires you to open ports from the server to your client in all the firewalls in between. Tunneling gets rid of the insecurity and the need of the firewall's rules.
- you need to connect to a third server you don't have direct access from your client. You could use a client app on the server via command line or use your graphical client app on your PC through the tunnel.
- if you have a service on the SSH server that only listen on localhost, you could connect from your PC using a tunnel. I.e. a mysql server could be administrated via a graphical app from your PC without needing to open ports on firewall or exposing the service to the whole network.
- Use it as a proxy to bypass HTTP inspection. Some companies do use proxies for PCs, but servers usually don't.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question because I couldn't explain this to someone who didn't have at least a general understanding of TCP/Port forwarding/Networking in general. I couldn't use this answer to, say, explain SSH forwarding to my Grandpa.

Comment: @Chipperyman well, there's laymen and there's laymen. If you're trying to explain dynamic port forwarding to your grandpa who doesn't know what an IP address is, then your grandpa should put you into a care home!

Comment: You write "SSH tunneling is the same as port forwarding,"   <-- That is not really correct. SSH tunneling does port forwarding. But you can have port forwarding with no ssh, no tunneling. There are programs called TCP remappers that listen on a port and forward to an IP:PORT.

Comment: @barlop: In the context of SSH, I’s say these are synonymous. In “the outside world”, some terms may refer to different things, but it’s SSH we’re talking about here.

Comment: @DanielB err, SSH got those terms from the outside world and AFAIK, didn't change them.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you are on Computer A and you connect to Computer B, so A initiates a connection to B.. Say it's web, so HTTP connection.  There's no Proxy there and no Encryption. No SSH, no SSH command used.  You could run that connection through SSH, that'd involve tunneling and port forwarding and would of course gain the benefit of encryption too, but tunneling which by the way always uses port forwarding, is not the most simple use of SSH.

You can have SSH without any "tunneling" so without encapsulating a protocol within it, by e.g. Say you are on Computer A and you want to access a command line on Computer B. SSH protocol can do that. And in fact i've seen a ssh -X, enable one to view a GUI on Computer B, where computer B ran Linux.  So SSH can do quite a bit even without tunneling. And you get SSH's encryption whenever using SSH.

What you can also do, is let's say you want to browse the web from an internet cafe. You can make an SSH connection from computer A, to computer B,  making a connection that is an SSH tunnel, it will encapsulate another protocol, e.g. requests to an HTTP proxy..  and at computer B, the web proxy will act, fetch the webpage and send it to computer A.  All the person at the Internet cafe sees, is an encrypted ssh connection between A and B.   Dynamic port forwarding would create a SOCKS proxy at B, and a SOCKS proxy can act as a web proxy.

You could use VNC to from A to B, but do it through an SSH connection.. so that's tunneling/encapsulating a VNC connection in through an SSH connection.

There is a concept in SSH of local port forwarding, and remote port forwarding(reverse tunnel).   That is which side listens and which side forwards.  Local is the typical. For example. A situation of ssh tunneling involves these elements..  ssh.exe (initiates the ssh connection, that's the ssh client).   sshd.exe (the ssh server, listens for ssh.exe to connect to it).   And the client and server of the encapsulated protocol. e.g. the VNC client and VNC server.  And you have the computers on which each of these are running.

Say your computers are A,B,C,D

```
A-runs VNC client
B runs SSH client
C runs SSH server
D runs VNC server
```

B connects to C.

A connects to B, then C forwards that to D.

Everything between B and C is encrypted.

Anything between A and B, or C and D, is not encrypted.

The SSH tunnel is between B and C.

Between A and B,  and between C and D, is the encapsulated protocol - VNC in this case.

We often do SSH and tunneling with just two computers. So  eg A runs VNC client and SSH client.  B runs VNC server and SSH server.

Now i'll get to what a reverse tunnel is and it is useful..

Suppose A is behind a NAT Router and B is behind a NAT Router.. If A wants to connect to VNC on B, then B has to do port forwarding on his router. (that's even without SSH).
Another way though, would be if B can initiate a connection to A, enabling A to view B. So you the techie send joe bloggs an executable and then run it and you view their computer. PChelpWare does this- enabling you to create such an executable.   But the process, of B can connect to you, can be done with SSH.

For example in a scenario of local ssh tunnel, you may have

```
CompA, runs VNC client and SSH client
CompB, runs VNC server and SSH server
```

So the tunnel and VNC connection go in the same direction.

A connects his SSH client(ssh.exe) to B's SSH server(sshd.exe).  (requires B to do port forwarding on his router).    ssh.exe on A then creates a port on A - the comp it is running on, which listens for a VNC connection.  That is the listening side of the tunnel. And also when the tunnel was constructed it was determined that B should forward to whatever IP:PORT, B in this case. Which is where the VNC server is.

CompA/PersonA, connects the VNC client to the port that ssh.exe has opened on A. And that will then get forwarded to B.

But here's the problem with that, with local ssh tunnel.  Suppose B has no idea how to do port forwarding on his router.

Then A cannot connect his SSH.EXE, his ssh client, to B's SSHD.EXE, B's ssh server.

Well, they could do a reverse SSH tunnel

```
A runs the SSH SERVER and VNC Client
B runs the SSH CLIENT and VNC Server..
```

B connects to A.. with a command that instructs that a reverse tunnel be created. So, the listening is done not local to where SSH.EXE was run(which is B), but the listening port is opened on A, even though B ran ssh.exe  So B connects to A and makes an SSH connection.  A now listens for the encapsulated protocol.

A then connects his VNC client to the port that opened on A, and views B.

B did not have to do port forwarding on his router. As all B had to do was initiate a connection.. There was no incoming connection to B.    That is what an SSH tunnel can do.

(note that nowadays  when A wants to view B they typically use a solution like teamviewer which probably involves both making an outgoing connection)

But anyhow that's a use of reverse ssh tunnel.

So whether to use an local ssh tunnel or a reverse one, depends on which side is blocking incoming.  or which side is behind a device blocking incoming for which you cannot control. e.g. a NAT router or firewall that you cannot control.

a Dynamic tunnel, is where A connects to B via SSH, and a SOCKS proxy is created at B. A SOCKS proxy is like a generic proxy.. which can imitate a bunch of different kind of proxies. So it can act as a Web proxy.  So if you were at an Internet cafe.. You could use a dynamic tunnel.  Connect to CompB and that's all the person running the internet cafe sees. The thing with a web proxy is it doesn't juse forward to one computer otherwise you'd only get one website. It forwards to whatever web server you request, enabling you to browse the web.

To do SSH with -L, listens on the local end, and does  port forwarding on the remote end, so with SSH -L, you do `SSH -L PORT:IP:PORT  user@sshserver -p 22`   where of PORT:IP:PORT  the first "port" is the port that ssh.exe will create locally for your e.g. VNC client to connect to.   and IP:PORT is the IP:PORT of the e.g. VNC server.  then you have sshserver -p 22   sshserver is an IP of the ssh server you are connecting to, and -p 22 means connect to it on port 22.  You might actually instead of PORT:IP:PORT, say  IP:PORT:IP:PORT  where the first IP is 0.0.0.0 or * which means any computer can connect.

SSH but with a reverse ssh tunnel, listens on the remote end, and does port forwarding locally.  So you do SSH -R PORT:IP:PORT where the first PORT is the port at the sshd.exe end that listens. And the IP:PORT is the IP:PORT of the e.g. VNC server, that that CompA, i.e. the comp running ssh.exe will forward to.  And it's also `SSH -R PORT:IP:PORT user@sshserver -p 22`

Dynamic SSH would be of the form `ssh -D 8080 <username>@192.168.1.1`

There is a case of somebody doing a reverse version..a reverse SSH -D. https://web.archive.org/web/20200618074454/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/842021/ssh-d-port-usernameserver-com-but-in-reverse   He ran an SSH server and wanted his friend to have access to his SSH proxy. So his friend would run ssh -D username@server.com But he didn't want his friend to have an SSH console too. There is no doubt a better way to prevent that, but what he did.. or asked to do.. Was He makes the SSH connection to his friend, but then have his friend access his SSH SOCKS proxy. So his friend has a proxy to access his SOCKS proxy! So he (the person-person A- setting his computer up so his friend could access his(A's) proxy) would type `ssh -R 24680:localhost:12345 remotehost`
And then, do `ssh -D 12345 localhost`  That ssh -R, means the first port specified (24680) will open up on CompB. And anything received on that(which is where B connects his web browser) will be sent to A and forwarded to port 12345 which is where A runs his SOCKS proxy. And the funny thing with how the SOCKS proxy is set up which is how SOCKS proxies are set up with SSH, is it requires its own ssh connection. That is not tunneling SSH through SSH.. The SOCKS requests are tunneled through SSH. But the ssh connection that makes the SOCKS proxy is a separate connection that comes from A connecting to his own ssh server on port 22. (in addition to the SSH connection A is making to B). That last example, the reverse ssh -D is a very complex use of SSH! The other uses (local,reverse and normal -D) are still complex but not as complex as the reverse -D example. I just added it for more completeness.

see also my answer to [Control raspberry via VNC from ouside LAN: how is this feasible without port forwarding?](https://superuser.com/questions/1723647/control-raspberry-via-vnc-from-ouside-lan-how-is-this-feasible-without-port-for/1725489#1725489)